# Not able to load .obj and .mtl

Tags: three.js, aframe

Not able to render the .obj and .mtl file on web using A-Frame

I've gone through the [Docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/primitives/a-obj-model.html) and tried what's mentioned. When I inspected, the HTML was loading but it didn't render on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
      <a-assets>
<!--         <a-asset-item id="tree-obj" src="assets/BisonPlains.obj"></a-asset-item> -->
<!--         <a-asset-item id="tree-mtl" src="assets/BisonPlains.mtl"></a-asset-item> -->
      </a-assets>

      <a-obj-model src="assets/BisonPlains.obj" mtl="assets/BisonPlain.mtl"></a-obj-model>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you serving files from a local web server? Do you see the files loading in the browser network panel? I recommend creating a runnable example for people to help. https://glitch.com/~aframe is a good option

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mousy-amethyst?path=index.html:18:7

Answer (score 0):

Two issues after first look:

1. URLs are incorrect. Go to the glitch assets panel to get the proper URLs. Corrected glitch:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sunny-ceramic?path=index.html:15:101

2. The texture images is missing `BisonPlains_BaseColor.png`

First thing I recommend is checking at the browser network panel and look for 404 errors. Make sure that all files load as expected before investigating further.

Comment: How do I change the render angle?

Comment: Not sure what you meant. Does the model load now? Can you elaborate what to you mean by angle?